# Does google maps personalize the walking time to your destination?

Tags: google, google-maps, google-maps-navigation

Google maps has a lot of data about how far and how fast you move around. When you search for a walking route to your destination is the app calculating the walking time based on your average walking speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not take into account *your* walking speed but assumes a *normal* walking speed. From [Google Maps help](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/92124954?hl=en)

> What is the Google Map walking speed? Is this a constant value or does it change depending on slope?
>
> > Normal walking speed is about 3 miles per hour - It does not adjust for distance travelled, nor for whether you are on a road or footpath.
> > It does adjust slightly for slope - it decreases more for uphill than it increases for downhill.

A user wanted customized speed, like you do and they were [suggested](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/34433227?hl=en) to raise a feature request.

Comment: I am usually incensed by suggestions that I do Google's work for it by telling it which features need to be implemented, mainly because I know that Google has never and never will actually implement any of my suggestions and it is a waste of time to think otherwise (for me).  However, there are some serious issues the lack of this feature causes, namely underestimating my walking speed causes it to suggest sub-optimal routes because it thinks it would take to long to walk to a particular public transportation pick up point or between points.

Comment: Also in general it ticks me off that *every* thread I find on Google's "support" page has already locked me out of adding my comment by the time I find it.  In part on principle (there is no reason to ever disable commenting short of inability to prevent spam, etc.) but also because the fact that I am still having these problems so much later indicates the Google is not doing a good job at these things.

Comment: Quite agree. They don't listen, don't discuss and implement what they think users need

Comment: Also 3mph is ridiculous considering a male in mid sixties is expected to do 5KM jog in 30 minutes